# Возможно ли заменить два вызова replace на один?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки

Делаю упражнение, и там по идее подразумевается только один вызов `replace`. У меня получается только двумя.

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли всё же сделать это одним?

Вот упражнение:

> Imagine you have written a story and used single quotation marks
> throughout to mark pieces of dialogue. Now you want to replace all the
> dialogue quotes with double quotes, while keeping the single quotes
> used in contractions like aren’t.
>
> Think of a pattern that distinguishes these two kinds of quote usage
> and craft a call to the replace method that does the proper
> replacement.

Вот мой код:

```js
let text = "'I'm the cook,' he said, 'it's my job.'";
// Change this call.
console.log(text.replace(/(^|[^a-zA-Z])'/g, "$1\"").replace(/'([^a-zA-Z]|$)/g, "\"$1"));
// → "I'm the cook," he said, "it's my job."
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
let text = "'I'm the cook,' he said, 'it's my job.'";
// Change this call.
console.log(text.replace(/\B'/g, "\""));
// → "I'm the cook," he said, "it's my job."
```

`\B` - Несловообразующая граница соответствует позиции, в которой предыдущий и следующий символы являются символами одного типа: либо оба должны быть словообразующими символами, либо несловообразующими. Начало и конец строки считаются несловообразующими символами.
**Важно:** `\B` не будет работать с кириллицей

---

UPD: Для символов иных кодировок можно сделать позитивный просмотр назад.
В данном случае отрицаем любую букву на латинице или кириллице:

```js
let text = "'I'm the cook,' he said, 'it's my job.'";
console.log(text.replace(/(?<![A-Za-zA-яЁё])'/g, "\""));
let text2 = "'Пример'с кириллицы.'Алфавит, 'Это'ж не с проста.'"
console.log(text2.replace(/(?<![A-Za-zA-яЁё])'/g, "\""));
```

Но и это не совсем законченный вариант, раз вопрос был не в решении конетретного примера, то стоит учесть, что будет пропущен знак припенания, тогда нам нужно будет условие иначе в регулярном выражении.

```js
const reg = /((?<![A-Za-zA-яЁё])'|'(?![A-Za-zA-яЁё]))/g
let text = "'I'm the cook' he said, 'it's my job'";
let text2 = "'Пример'с без точки в конце' Тест 'Это'ж не с проста'";
console.log(text.replace(reg, "\""));
console.log(text2.replace(reg, "\""));
```

Comment: Наверное, надо еще добавить, что работает только для символов латинского алфавита.

Comment: Красивое решение, спасибо

Comment: Да, действительно, это работает только для символов латинского алфавита. А как же границы слов на других алфавитах? Получается, для них нужно более сложное решение?

Comment: @OlgaClimova, дополнил ответ

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, спасибо за замечание.

Answer (score 2):

Границы слова, поддерживающие Юникод:

- `(?<!\p{Alphabetic}\p{M}*)` - левая граница слова (блок предварительного просмотора назад, отменяющий совпадение, если сразу перед текушей позицией есть любой алфавитный символ + ноль и более диакритических знаков)
- `(?!\p{Alphabetic})` - правая граница слова (блок предварительного просмотора вперёд, отменяющий совпадение, если сразу после текушей позиции есть любой алфавитный символ).

Решение, которое поддреживает все буквы Юникода:

```js
const regex = /(?<!\p{Alphabetic}\p{M}*)'|'(?!\p{Alphabetic})/gu;
let text = "'I'm the cook' he said, 'it's my job'\n'Пример'с без точки в конце' Тест 'Это'ж не с проста'\n'Eł'z, ńóść'";
console.log(text.replace(regex, '"'));
```

Регулярное выражение тут

```
/(?<!\p{Alphabetic}\p{M}*)'|'(?!\p{Alphabetic})/gu
```

См. [пример работы](https://regex101.com/r/FytJwW/1).